# How to not override values in registry with .reg file?

Tags: registry, overriding, regedit

I need to save registry value only if the key is absent.
How can I do this?

Example:

"key1": 1

My reg file:

"key1": 2
"key2": 2

After execution I wish to see registry 
"key1": 1, "key2": 2

Is it possible?